# How to add additional attribute for dynamic object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

**How to make disable or readonly if FlagAccessEdit =false?**

```
public static MvcHtmlString CCheckBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
string name,object htmlAttributes, 
bool FlagAccessEdit = true, bool FlagAccessView = true)
{

            if (!FlagAccessView)
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            else if (!FlagAccessEdit && FlagAccessView)
            {
                return htmlHelper.CheckBox(name, htmlAttributes);
            }
            else
                return htmlHelper.CheckBox(name, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: How to make disable or readonly id FlagAccessEdit =false?

Comment: If this comment is part of the question you should edit it into the question and not as a comment.

Comment: The answer by Ashish Shukla shows one solution, but what would be the point. There is no such thing as a readonly checkbox, and disabling it would mean you always post back `false` even if the checkbox is initially displayed as checked (`true`) which would no doubt screw up your app. If you want to do this, generate a hidden input for the value a some text (say "Yes" or "No")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the existing htmlAttribute and add disabled or read-only based on your condition. Below is the correct code

**Helper method**

```
public static MvcHtmlString CCheckBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        string name, object htmlAttributes,bool FlagAccessEdit = true, 
        bool FlagAccessView = true)
    {
        //get the htmlAttribute
        IDictionary<string, object> attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);

        if (!FlagAccessView)
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        else if (!FlagAccessEdit && FlagAccessView)
        {
            //Add the disabled attribute
            attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
            return htmlHelper.CheckBox(name, attributes);
        }
        else
        {
            return htmlHelper.CheckBox(name, htmlAttributes);
        }

    }
```

**Call the method like below**

```
@Html.CCheckBox("chkCheckbox", new { id="chkDemo"},false,true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ashish .Its working fine as expected :)